# Understanding the negate() function example from Eloquent Javascript (Chapter 6)

Tags: javascript

As a new javascript developer, I have spent some time with this code snippit from [Chapter 6 of Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter6.html), I am still trying to understand the following code example :

```
function negate(func) {
  return function(x) {
    return !func(x);
  };
}
var isNotNaN = negate(isNaN);
document.writeln(isNotNaN(NaN));
```

Where it particular loses me is the following line, I just don't understand the call in general and where the variable/value for **NaN** comes from:

```
document.writeln(isNotNaN(NaN));
```

Comment: I do understand what the concept of NaN (Not a Number) is, what I do not understand is how the line in question works in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think xdazz pretty much covered it, but since you said you still don't get it maybe it would help to hear the explanation in somebody else's words.

This line:

```
var isNotNaN = negate(isNaN);
```

...declares a variable `isNotNan` that is assigned equal to the result of a call to the `negate()` function, passing `isNan` as a parameter.

That parameter `isNan` is actually a function as [described by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN), but `negate()` would accept any function as a parameter, you could say for example `var isNotFinite = negate(isFinite);`.

Now the `negate()` function actually creates and returns another function, so after that line runs `isNotNan` references that returned function, which means you can call it as `isNotNan(someVal)`.

So then the line:

```
document.writeln(isNotNaN(NaN));
```

... calls `isNotNan()` and passes it `NaN` as a parameter, and the result is written out to the document.

> *"I just don't understand...where the variable/value for NaN comes from"*

`NaN` is a property of the global object. To oversimplify, it is a constant provided to you by the JS environment.

Regarding how the `negate()` function works, it relies on the concept of "closures", which means that functions declared inside `negate()` have access to its variables and parameters *even after `negate()` completes.* You'll notice that the returned function references the `func` parameter. So when you call the returned function via `isNotNaN()` it can still access that original `func` parameter that is set to the `isNan` function.

The effect is kind of like doing this:

```
var isNotNaN = function(x) {
    return !isNan(x);
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm still think I'm getting grips to code excerpts that read like `isNotNaN(NaN)`, in other words - if I'm not mistaken - **is Not Not a Number (Not A Number)**. I think once my brain has cooled down and grown more used to it, things will make sense.

Comment: Cool. For the particular chapter you're reading, the `isNan` function is just an example so try not to get too hung up on it. It could be any function there.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. Maybe I do not understand is fully yet, but what is the purpose of modifying a function name? Because that is what you are doing, right?

Comment: @Marciano - no, this creates a new function with its own name that does the opposite of the original function.  The original function still exists with its original name.

Answer (score 2):

`negate` take a function as parameter, and returns a new function which returns the opposite result of the original function.

[NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) is A value representing Not-A-Number.

> NaN is a property of the global object.
>
> The initial value of NaN is Not-A-Number — the same as the value of
>   Number.NaN. In modern browsers, NaN is a non-configurable,
>   non-writable property. Even when this is not the case, avoid
>   overriding it.

NaN is a property of the global object, So it is `window.NaN`.

And note `typeof NaN` returns `number`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of NaN and negate, I do understand the concept (I hope!), but what I am trying to understand is that particular line - it's still bamboozling me.